# How to print page number through css in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, jspdf

Though there are many answers for printing page number through CSS. Most common method to add page number by using `counter` suggested by [this article](https://alistapart.com/article/boom/). This works when the content of a page is less. But when the content inside `div` is large, in this context the page number is visible but it is repetitive.

I am trying to print large table which split over `n` number of pages. In which case I tried to use `tfoot` like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html-to-pdf-example-answer-bldrmz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but the page number is repetitive. I want the page number to be incremented by page like 1, 2,...  with its data and design (CSS).

I tried [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) it works fine for page number but cannot implement its design as when it convert my html to pdf, it looses all my CSS. I have tried this way in jsPDF

```
const htmlToPrint = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;
const doc = new jsPDF();
console.log(doc.getFontList());
doc.setFont('times','normal','normal');
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.html(htmlToPrint, {
  fontFaces:[
    {
      family:"Times-Roman",
      style:"normal",
      src:[
        {
          url:"/assets/fonts/TIMES.ttf",
          format:"truetype"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  callback: function (doc) {
    const pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages(); //Total Page Number
    for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
      doc.setPage(i);

      let pageCurrent = doc.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber; //Current Page
      doc.setFontSize(12);
      doc.text('' + pageCurrent, 196, 285);
    }

    doc.save("myDemo.pdf");
  },
  x: 10,
  y: 10
});
```

I have tried [pdf-make](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/) for the same purpose but when I convert my HTML to its JSON format the size of the JSON is around `20mb`, which occupies all the browser memory and browser window get crashed.

My requirement is to print large table with its CSS and its data as a book. How can I go forward to achieve my requirement. I am trying to find out the solution through internet but none of them are working correctly for me. How to print large html table with its CSS and page number in it.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda had a similar problem not long a go. Follows the algorithm of my solution.

- Converts from DOM('div') to image;
- Cut/Split the image to fit in one page;
- Add images to pdf;

```js
const element = document.getElementbyId('myTable');
const MAX_HEIGHT_PDF_PAGE = 800;//in px
let doc = new jsPdf();

domtoimage.toPng(element).then((imageDataUrl)=> {
  //get element height;  
  
  //numberOfPages necessary = elementHeight / MAX_HEIGHT_PDF_PAGE
  
  // split imageDateUrl into pages, we're gonna get an imageArr
  let imageArr = [];
  for(let image of imageArr) {//addpages and images to pdf
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(image, 'PNG',x, y, width, height);
  }  
})

//dump js pdf
doc.output('dataurl');
```

---

#### Edit(code for converting pdf -> image)

```js
function _pdfToJpeg(doc) {
  //load pdf with lib pdf.js
  let pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: doc.output('arraybuffer')}).promise;
  let jpegBase64Arr = [];

  for(let i = 1; i <= this.totalPages; i++) {//iter through pages
    //load page 
    let page = await pdf.getPage(i);
    let vp = page.getViewport({scale: 1.0});

    //dummy canvas just to render pdf page
    let c = document.createElement('canvas');
    let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    c.width = vp.width;
    c.height = vp.height;

    let renderCtx = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: vp
    };

    //render page on a canvas 
    await page.render(renderCtx).promise;

    //convert pdf on the canvas and converts to image
    jpegBase64Arr.push(c.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1));
    c.remove();
  }

  return new Promise(resolve=> resolve(jpegBase64Arr));//array of images(pdfs pages)
}
```

- Lib used: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

###### Note:

I'm not completely sure about the syntax.

Comment: In this way the header are not repeatitive. In addition to your algorithm, before converting DOM('div') to image, the steps that I want to add is First convert the DOM to PDF with CSS then Convert Pdf pages to Image then dump. But I didnt found the package for converting  pdf to image. Every package I found are dependent on some other package like GhostScript and GraphicMajik etc. Is there any simpler package that convert pdf pages to images so that it can be added to jsPDF. It would be very helpful if someone shows me a path.

Comment: I added a sample code for converting from pdf to image :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, jspdf does not work with css but you can use jspdf along with html2canvas.

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 doc.addHTML($('#htmlToPrint')[0], function () {
     doc.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```

Add HTML2Canvas JS and then use doc.addHTML()